# What does the unary operator ~ do in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I came across a line of code using Python's numpy that looked like this:

```
~array([0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2])
```

And it gave the output:

```
array([-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1])
```

Does the unary operator (~) take an array and apply A -> -(A+1)

If so, whats the point?

Comment: It appears to be bitwise negation, just like it is in C. The operator applies to normal Python integers (at least it does for me in 2.5. Maybe I should upgrade...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Chris Lutz' comment is correct.

~ is the [bitwise negation operator](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.inv)

It looks like it turns A to -(A+1) because on many modern computers, negative numbers are represented as the [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) of the corresponding positive integer, where the number is subtracted from `2^(bit length)` (that's "two to the power of bit length", not "two exclusive or bit length"...).

In such a system, -1 would be represented as all ones.
Of course, so would the sum of a number and its bitwise negative, so we have the situation where

```
a + ~a = -1        =>
    ~a = -1 - a    =>
    ~a = -(a + 1)
```

as you noticed.

Answer (score 4):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT

The reason why you end up with negative numbers is how they are represented in binary form:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Answer (score 2):

The ~ is the [ones' complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement%23Ones.27_complement) operator and if you're using with ints it can be used in any python program (it's not exclusively of numpy)

Comment: I'm not so sure, the following line:
~list[1,2,3]
fails since the unary operator was not defined for lists, the class object has to have them defined just like any other operator.

Comment: @Hooked I think they meant that you can do things slike `~6`

Answer (score 0):

The point is to be able to take the complement of the vales in an array. In the case of numpy it appears to be shorthand for the following:

```
>>> map(lambda e: ~e, [0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2])
[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1]
```