# Accessing NumPy array elements not in a given index list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array with the shape (100, 170, 256). And I have an array consisting of indexes [0, 10, 20, 40, 70].

I can get the sub-arrays corresponding to the indexes as follows:

```
sub_array = array[..., index]
```

This returns an array with the shape (100, 170, 5) as expected. Now, I am trying to take the complement and get the sub-array NOT corresponding to those indexes. So, I did:

```
sub_array = array[..., ~index]
```

This still returns me an array of shape (100, 170, 5) for some reason. I wonder how to do this complement operation of these indexes in python?

[EDIT]

Also tried:

```
sub_array = array[..., not(index.any)]
```

However, this does not do the thing I want as well (getting array of shape (100, 170, 251).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

have a look at what ~index gives you - I think it is:

```
array([ -1, -11, -21, -41, -71])
```

So, your call

```
sub_array = array[..., ~index]
```

will return 5 entries, corresponding to indices [ -1, -11, -21, -41, -71] i.e. 255, 245, 235, 215 and 185 in your case

Similarly, not(index.any) gives

```
False
```

hence why your second try doesn't work

This should work:

```
sub_array = array[..., [i for i in xrange(256) if i not in index]]
```

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds or so.  Upvoting.  :)

Answer (score 31):

The way you have your data, the simplest approach is to use [`np.delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

```
sub_array = np.delete(array, index, axis=2)
```

Alternatively, the logical operators you were trying to use can be applied with boolean arrays as @DSM suggests:

```
mask = np.ones(a.shape[2], dtype=bool)
mask[index] = False
sub_array = array[:,:, mask]
```

(I wouldn't call your array `array` but I followed the names in your question)

Answer (score 30):

The question is answered but I propose a benchmark of the three methods here.

**Fastest solution is boolean mask** (with small and larger index array size)

```
mask = np.ones(arr.size, dtype=bool)
mask[indexes] = False
result = arr[mask]
```

It is 2000 times faster than the list comprehension and marginaly faster than `np.delete`

#### Code to reproduce

Three proposed solutions: list comprehension (`sol1`), boolean mask (`sol2`) or `np.delete` (`sol3`)

```
d = 100000
a = np.random.rand(d)
idx = np.random.randint(d, size = 10)


# list comprehension
def sol1(arr, indexes):
    return arr[[i for i in range(arr.size) if i not in indexes]]
sol1(a, idx)
# Out[30]: array([0.13044518, 0.68564961, 0.03033223, ..., 0.03796257, 0.40137137, 0.45403929])

# boolean mask
def sol2(arr, indexes):
    mask = np.ones(arr.size, dtype=bool)
    mask[indexes] = False
    return arr[mask]
sol2(a, idx)
# Out[32]: array([0.13044518, 0.68564961, 0.03033223, ..., 0.03796257, 0.40137137, 0.45403929])

# np.delete
def sol3(arr, indexes):
    return np.delete(arr, indexes)
sol3(a, idx)
# Out[36]: array([0.13044518, 0.68564961, 0.03033223, ..., 0.03796257, 0.40137137, 0.45403929])
```

#### Results

```
%timeit sol1(a, idx)
384 ms ± 2.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit sol2(a, idx)
154 µs ± 15.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit sol3(a, idx)
194 µs ± 18.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)


idx = np.random.randint(d, size = 1000)
%timeit sol1(a, idx)
386 ms ± 7.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit sol2(a, idx)
171 µs ± 11.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit sol3(a, idx)
205 µs ± 10.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

I tend to work with boolean arrays rather than indices where possible to avoid this issue.  You could use `in1d` to get one, even though it isn't very pretty:

```
>>> arr[..., index].shape
(100, 170, 5)
>>> arr[..., np.in1d(np.arange(arr.shape[-1]),index)].shape
(100, 170, 5)
>>> arr[..., ~np.in1d(np.arange(arr.shape[-1]),index)].shape
(100, 170, 251)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming `index` is a numpy array - if so, the explanation for what the tilde operator is doing can be found here:

[What does the unary operator ~ do in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428014/what-does-the-unary-operator-do-in-numpy)

As for what you're trying to accomplish, you could assemble a complementary index array:

```
notIndex = numpy.array([i for i in xrange(256) if i not in index])
```

And then use `notIndex` instead of `index`.