# Translating mathematical functions from MATLAB to Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, sum, sign

I am currently working on a project which involves translating a program which runs in MATLAB to Python to increase speed and efficiency. However, I have hit a stumbling block. First, I am confused as to what the tilde(~) indicates in MATLAB, and how to represent that in a corresponding way in python. Second, I have been searching through documentation and I'm also having a difficult time finding an equivalent function for the 'sign' function in MATLAB.

```
    indi = ~abs(indexd);
    wav = (sum(sum(wv)))/(length(wv)*(length(wv)-1));
    thetau = (sign(sign(wv - wav) - 0.1) + 1)/2;
    thetad = (sign(sign(wav - wv) - 0.1) + 1)/2;
```

I have already converted indexd, and wv, which are from a previous section of code, to numpy arrays. What is the most efficient Pythonic way to replace the ~ and sign functions?

Comment: The [tilde operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/symbol-reference.html#bsv2dx9-1) means logical `NOT` and [`sign`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/sign.html) returns the sign of a numeric value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using `numpy`, then you also use `~` to invert things just like MATLAB.  See: [What does the unary operator ~ do in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428014/what-does-the-unary-operator-do-in-numpy).   The `sign` function also exists in `numpy`.  You use [`numpy.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html).  Therefore, the code above is simply:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> indi = ~np.abs(indexd)
>>> wav = (np.sum(wv))/(len(wv)*(len(wv)-1))
>>> thetau = (np.sign(np.sign(wv - wav) - 0.1) + 1)/2
>>> thetad = (np.sign(np.sign(wav - wv) - 0.1) + 1)/2
```

Be advised that using `length` in MATLAB on matrices finds the largest dimension in the matrix whereas `numpy` uses `len` to give you the total number of rows in the matrix.  Assuming that the number of rows in `wv` is greater than or equal to the number of columns in `wv`, then the above code will work as you expect.  However, if you have more columns than rows, that you'd need is to find the maximum of the dimensions and use that instead... so:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> maxdim = np.max(wv.shape)
>>> indi = ~np.abs(indexd)
>>> wav = (np.sum(wv))/(maxdim*(maxdim-1))
>>> thetau = (np.sign(np.sign(wv - wav) - 0.1) + 1)/2
>>> thetad = (np.sign(np.sign(wav - wv) - 0.1) + 1)/2
```

The above call to [`numpy.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) actually sums over all of the dimensions by default, so there's no need to call nested `sum` calls to sum over the entire matrix (Thanks Divakar!).

Totally recommend you go here and see the awesome table and guide from translating from MATLAB to `numpy`: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)

Comment: Actually, you can avoid `unravel` with `.sum()`.

Comment: @Divakar - Thanks.  I actually forgot about that.  Changed my post.

Comment: Or keep what you said about `np.sum` and do something like `np.sum(wv)
`. Without the mention of `axis`, it unravels internally.

Comment: @Divakar - Huh.  I thought by default it defaulted to `axis=0`, which means go over all of the columns.  Interesting.

Comment: @Divakar - Interesting.  Will definitely modify my post then.  Thanks!  BTW, you're right.  It defaults to `axis=None`, which means to iterate over all of the dimensions.  Thanks!